# Cannot get Ninject.Extensions.Conventions to work

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, ninject, ninject-extensions

I've been trying to get Ninject.Extensions.Conventions for (Ninject 3+) working, with no luck. I boiled it down to a found sample console app, and I can't even get that going. Here's what I have:

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var kernel = new StandardKernel();
            kernel.Bind(x => x
               .FromThisAssembly()
               .SelectAllClasses()
               .BindAllInterfaces());

            var output = kernel.Get<IConsoleOutput>();
            output.HelloWorld();

            var service = kernel.Get<Service>();
            service.OutputToConsole();

            Console.ReadLine();
        }

        public interface IConsoleOutput
        {
            void HelloWorld();
        }

        public class ConsoleOutput : IConsoleOutput
        {
            public void HelloWorld()
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
            }
        }

        public class Service
        {
            private readonly IConsoleOutput _output;
            public Service(IConsoleOutput output)
            {
                _output = output;
            }

            public void OutputToConsole()
            {
                _output.HelloWorld();
            }
        }
    }
```

I've also tried various combos of  **FromAssembliesMatching**, **SelectAllTypes**, **BindDefaultInterfaces**, etc. Everything throws the Error activating . No matching bindings are available, and the type is not self-bindable.

Just for sanity, if I do a manual binding with:

```
kernel.Bind<IConsoleOutput>().To<ConsoleOutput>();
```

Everything works just fine. So clearly I'm just missing something.

Comment: Perhaps because you're classes and interface are internal.

Comment: I don't think that's the issue, I have the exact same issue on my primary app, which is more standard in it's construction.

Comment: Just for debugging, you might want to specify a binding generator (+ implement it) then set a break point inside the binding generator to see which "classes", or what ever you specify, are found.
We are using ninject 3 and conventions are working just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is caused, as sam suggested, by the types not being public. They are inner types of the non-public "Program" class.

Make Program public or add `.IncludingNonPublicTypes()`:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x
    .FromThisAssembly()
    .IncludingNonPublicTypes()
    .SelectAllClasses()
    .BindAllInterfaces());
```

(I have verified that either works, and your code doesn't).

And here is your official source:
https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions.Test/IntegrationTests/NonPublicTypesTests.cs

Note: In older versions of Ninject this method was called `IncludeNonePublicTypes` (None vs Non).

Comment: The method should be spelled IncludingNonPublicTypes() notice the e is gone after Non

Comment: You are correct. However the ninject interface spells it this way. See https://github.com/ninject/ninject.extensions.conventions/blob/master/src/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/Syntax/IIncludingNonePublicTypesSyntax.cs

Comment: I was hoping the Ninject designers would see my comment and change it. I guess it's not worth making a breaking change just so something is spelled correctly though.

Comment: They ought to correct it, and leave the old one around for compatibility purposes, and throw a `deprecated` attribute on the incorrect one.