# Does Ninject Conventions only work for public classes?

Tags: c#, ninject, ninject-extensions

I started using Ninject for my project, to automatically bind all subclasses of an abstract class. The binding for this is -- nice and easy -- as follows:

```
kernel.Bind(x => x.FromThisAssembly()
    .SelectAllClasses().
    .InheritedFrom<AbstractGenerator>()
    .BindBase());
```

However, I found that this doesn't work. After some experimenting I found that the reason for this not working is that all my implementations (and the abstract class) are marked *internal*.

I could imagine this to be some security feature, to prevent bindings from leaking internals to the outside. But I can add explicit bindings for these classes. Hence, my question is: Does anybody know whether this is intended behavior? Is there some way to fix this, other than making all my classes public?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Put a `.IncludingNonPublicTypes()` before the `.SelectAllClasses()` and your bindings will also work for internal classes.

Also see this question: [Cannot get Ninject.Extensions.Conventions to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793095/cannot-get-ninject-extensions-conventions-to-work/18875070#18875070)

I don't think it's about security. I guess it's about design and maybe about performance: choosing from only the public types takes less time than choosing from all types.

Comment: Thanks, this was what I was looking for. Only that I search for the quantification after SelectAllClasses(), because that's where all the other quantification happens... Sorry about the duplicate, but I failed to find this other post...