# Ninject.Extensions.Conventions won't bind single interface

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, ninject

Can't get one of the samples from the Ninject.Extensions.Conventions [Github page](https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions) to work, version 3.3.0. `BindDefaultInterface()` works no problem, but `BindSingleInterface()`, as shown below, returns an exception of `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Sequence contains no elements'`.

I'm aware of the similarly titled SO question
[Cannot get Ninject.Extensions.Conventions to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18793095/cannot-get-ninject-extensions-conventions-to-work/18875070#18875070). This is not the same (also, my Program class is public, which was the crux of that issue).

This is stripped down to as simple of a console app as we can get I think.

```
using System;
using Ninject;
using Ninject.Extensions.Conventions;

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind(x => x
           .FromThisAssembly()
           .SelectAllClasses()
           .BindSingleInterface());

        var output = kernel.Get<IConsoleOutput>();
        output.HelloWorld();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public interface IConsoleOutput
    {
        void HelloWorld();
    }

    public class ConsoleOutput : IConsoleOutput
    {
        public void HelloWorld()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello world!");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Based on this wiki ( https://github.com/ninject/Ninject.Extensions.Conventions/wiki/Overview ) you are missing the 4th step which would be the *configuration*. Try chaining a `.Configure(b => b.InSingletonScope())` right after the *BindSingleInterface* method and check if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is, that Ninject tries to also bind your `Program` class, and because it doesn't implement any interface you get `System.InvalidOperationException`. If you add some dummy interface on `Program` class, your code will run without problems.

But probably you should consider whether to use rather methods like `BindDefaultInterface`or `BindAllInterfaces`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from the fact that Ninject captures your `Program` class which does not implement any interface, and fails to bind a single interface to it.

You may try to replace the line :

```
.SelectAllClasses()
```

with

```
 .SelectAllClasses().Where(t => t.GetInterfaces().Any())
```